# Where is the application.rb file located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im new to Ruby On Rails.Im using Ruby version 1.8.7 and Rails version 2.3.8.I created a controller SayHello using

```
ruby script/generate controller SayHello
```

The application works as expected, but i cant find the application.rb file. Where is the application.rb file located ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're looking for the application controller which was named application.rb prior to rails 2.3 but is since application_controller.rb.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#application-controller-renamed

controllers>application_controller.rb

Answer (score 4):

This file is new to rails 3, in rails 2 most of the things now in application.rb are in the environment.rb.

Comment: application.rb new in rails 3?!!

Comment: The `config/application.rb` I meant is new to rails 3. didn't thought of that the OP could mean the controller.